# Use different records from one table to combine it with the different entries of other

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables. Employee and Qualifications.

**Employee**

```
Emp_id   Name   Qualification1   Qualification2    Qualification3
10001   xxxxxx         1              3                5
10002   yyyyyy         3              2                       
.......
......
.....
```

**Qualifications**

```
Qual_ID   Qual_name
    1      B.Tech
    2      MCA
    3      M.Tech
```

How can i use join query to get the following output

```
Emp_ID   Name    Qual1   Qual2   Qual3
10001   xxxxxxx  B.Tech   MCA     pppp
10002   yyyyyyy  B.Tech   
......
.....
.....
```

Comment: You should have another table `EmployeeQualifications` probably. This doesn't seem to be in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). That way looking for Employees with a particular qualification won't require searching 3 columns and you can cope with Employees with more than 3 qualifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
Select E.Emp_ID,E.Name,Q1.Qual_Name,Q2.Qual_Name, Q3.Qual_Name
From 
    Employees AS E
    INNER JOIN Qualifications As Q1 ON E.Qualification1=Q1.Qual_ID
    INNER JOIN Qualifications As Q2 ON E.Qualification2=Q2.Qual_ID
    INNER JOIN Qualifications As Q3 ON E.Qualification3=Q3.Qual_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT e.emp_id, 
       e.name, 
       q1.qual_name, 
       q2.qual_name, 
       q3.qual_name, 
FROM   employee e 
       INNER JOIN qualifications q1 
               ON e.qualification1 = q1.qual_id 
       INNER JOIN qualifications q2 
               ON e.qualification2 = q2.qual_id 
       INNER JOIN qualifications q3 
               ON e.qualification3 = q2.qual_id
```

Comment: @Romil can you tell me why this is not working...?
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8431d/4/0

Comment: @VishalSuthar, You put the q1.Qual_ID for all inner join conditions.

Comment: @VishalSuthar,  I made typo mistake in hurry. Thanks. I have updated the post.

Comment: @Romil So can you give me the correct solution becos I didn't see any update in the post?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8431d/15/0)

```
Select
    Emp_id, Name, 
    (Select Qual_name from Qualifications where Qualifications.Qual_ID = Employee.Qualification1) as Qual1,
    (Select Qual_name from Qualifications where Qualifications.Qual_ID = Employee.Qualification2) as Qual2,
    (Select Qual_name from Qualifications where Qualifications.Qual_ID = Employee.Qualification3) as Qual3
From Employee
```

Comment: @downvoter Will this query not work ? Can you bother to comment ?